# Error message while importing "TextBlob" package

Tags: python, textblob

I have installed python "TextBlob" package and it is available in the below location.

```
c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

(checked through runing command (pip show TextBlob)

When i am trying to run the command "`Import TextBlob`" is showing up error as

> No module named 'TextBlob'.

I have changed the current directory to `"c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages".`
still no luck.

Could anyone reply on this ?

Comment: what did you use to install it? Pip? Conda?

Comment: First i tried with pip install , later i tried with conda.. even conda installation failed. 
Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/

Answer (score 1):

Myself able to find the solution for this error.

1. uninstalled TextBlob using - pip uninstall TextBlob
2. installed textblob using command - conda install -c conda-forge textblob
3. Lastly ran the command in command prompt - python -m textblob.download_corpora